# Cannot redirect to login page if user not authenticated using constructor

Tags: php

I have an Admin controller which handles the user login and other admin functionality like managing a basic cms. In the constructor I check if the users session present which is set once they login. If not and they try to access a restricted page, they should be redirected. If I redirect to another page then when going to the login page I get redirected right away as obviously that check is done in the constructor, but as soon as I try to redirect to the login page I get an error:

> This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. Try
>   clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
class Admin extends Controller {

    public function __construct()

    {

        if(!isLoggedIn()) {

            redirect('admin/login');
        }

        $this->AuthModel = $this->model('Auth');

    }
```

isLoggedIn is a function:

```
function isLoggedIn() {

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['browser']) && $_SESSION['browser'] == $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Login method:

```
public function login()
{
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    $data = [

    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
    'email_error' => '',
    'pass_error' => '',
    'no_user' => '',
    'pass_wrong' => ''

    ];

    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        $data['email_error'] = 'Invalid email address <br />';
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))) {

        $data['pass_error'] = 'Password required';
    }

    if(!empty(trim($_POST['email'])) && !$this->AuthModel->getUserByEmail($email)) {

        $data['no_user'] = 'Email does not exist';
    }


    if(!empty($data['email_error']) || !empty($data['pass_error']) || !empty($data['no_user'])) {

        $this->view('admin/login', $data);

    } else {

        $loggedInUser = $this->AuthModel->login($email, $password);

        if($loggedInUser) {

            $this->CreateUserSession($loggedInUser);


        } else {

            $data['pass_wrong'] = 'Incorrect login details';
            $this->view('admin/login', $data);
        }
    }

} else {

    $data = [

        'email' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'email_error' => '',
        'pass_error' => '',
        'no_user' =>'',
        'pass_wrong' => ''
    ];

    $this->view('admin/login', $data);
  }
}
```

Comment: what kind of error you got ?

Comment: @Robin, I showed the error in my initial question. This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I think it gets stuck in a loop?

Comment: have you tried with a header location ?

Comment: @Robin, "redirect" is a function which is header location. `function redirect($page) {
 
 header('location:' .URLROOT . '/' . $page);
}`

Comment: i think your function is still running you are not logged so the function run and run again

Comment: Yeah, I think it's stuck in a loop. But what can I do to fix it? I want the function to run in the constructor instead of having to put it in every single method in my class. I would be seriously going against the DRY principle!

Comment: andput exit(); just after you redirect?

Comment: Already tried exit(); no difference.....

Comment: What does the structure look like? Perhaps `admin/login` extends `admin` and that constructor is called automatically again?

Comment: show us your login controller?? or admin/login implementation

Comment: I think you should try with put  if(!isLoggedIn()) {

            redirect('admin/login');

        } in diff function as its in construct function its call every time so its going into infinnite loop as i assume. In which page your construct method ?

Comment: @Sohel0415, I have added the login method to original question

Comment: @jeroen, my Admin controller extends my Controller class

Comment: and which controller you are using for login function??

Comment: Just showing some methods without context does not tell us much...

Comment: I have updated the question to show the start of the class. The login method goes right under the constructor.

Comment: @jeroen, apologies. What else can I post for you? I just didn't want to post 100's of lines of code unnecessarily

Comment: Well, there you go, when you call your `login` controller, the `admin` constructor gets executed first, causing an end-less redirect. You should take the `login` controller out of the `admin` class.

Comment: @jeroen, I suspected as much but how do I get around it without calling isLoggedIn() in every single method instead of the constructor? It makes more sense to run it in the constructor

Comment: @user8463989 I just edited my comment :-)

Comment: @jeroen, so I should have a separate controller JUST for login?

Comment: Yes, you should put it somewhere else as it does not require authentication, it is a public page so it should not be part of the `admin` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using same `controller` for `login` and other functionalities. Every time it checks for `authentication` and it gets no. And it `loops` over again. try to implement your login `functionalities` in a separate `Controller`.

Comment: That makes sense. I wanted to have the login and other functionality all under ADMIN though.

Comment: and you are checking for authentication for login too, that's why you are having this trouble